# Send ID instead Name in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

### Problem:

i want to send ID to database table instead of Name. but i want to display Name in a field instead of ID.
it work's well while i send it through combo box. but i don,t know how it work with Search field. the php code is given below:

```
<font> <b>Name: </b></font>
<?php

include("database/db.php");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM table";

$result = $link->query($sql); ?>
<select name="ID">
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $ad_id = $row["ID"];
          $name= $row['Name'];
           ?>
       <option  value="<?php echo $ad_id; ?>"><?php echo  $name; ?></option>


<?php
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: _"it through combo box. but i don,t know how it work with field"_ what? What field?

Comment: I'm still confused, what do you mean with search field?  your code shows no search function,

Comment: yes brother i can'nt mention Search function in the above code but when i send it through text field it show all the field along with id's. actually i want to Search a name with reletive id. and when i send the name it actually send the id to database.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT *  FROM table WHERE ID = 1";`

Comment: As per your updated question you mean user can enter the name to search box and after click on search button, it will send id to database for search sql

Comment: try using concatenate id and name in query to display in search box.

Comment: Yes Brother exactly @Mukesh25

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you can use the auto complete text box in php from mysql by using ajax call it will fulfill your requirement for search by name.

There are some link available in web as you can search and implement but you have to do some changes for the ID contact with NAME

[Autosuggest ref 1](http://phpcoderzone.blogspot.in/2012/11/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html)

[Autosuggest link ref 2](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/02/autocomplete-textbox-from-database-php-jquery.html)

[JQUERY UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)